# SQL Query with Multiple Possible Tables and an Exclusion Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have multiple possible data tables (created to support parallel processing) to search against to find a match, and another table containing entries to exclude.  The tables are defined as follows, along with some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD_1
( 
    PERSON_ID       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    RELATIONSHIP        CHAR (1) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT HOUSEHOLD_1_PK PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID, HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID, RELATIONSHIP) ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_1 VALUES (1, 1, 'H');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_1 VALUES (2, 1, 'S');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_1 VALUES (3, 1, 'D');

CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD_2
( 
    PERSON_ID       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    RELATIONSHIP        CHAR (1) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT HOUSEHOLD_2_PK PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID, HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID, RELATIONSHIP) ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_2 VALUES (4, 4, 'H');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_2 VALUES (5, 4, 'S');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_2 VALUES (6, 4, 'D');

CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD_3
( 
    PERSON_ID       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    RELATIONSHIP        CHAR (1) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT HOUSEHOLD_3_PK PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID, HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID, RELATIONSHIP) ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_3 VALUES (7, 7, 'H');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_3 VALUES (8, 7, 'S');
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_3 VALUES (9, 7, 'D');

CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD_DELETIONS
( 
    PERSON_ID       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    RELATIONSHIP        CHAR (1) NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT HOUSEHOLD_DELETIONS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID, HOUSEHOLD_HEAD_ID, RELATIONSHIP) ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD_DELETIONS VALUES (9, 7, 'D');

CREATE TABLE CLOSED_ACCOUNTS
( 
    PERSON_ID       NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT CLOSED_ACCOUNTS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID) ENABLE
);

INSERT INTO CLOSED_ACCOUNTS VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO CLOSED_ACCOUNTS VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO CLOSED_ACCOUNTS VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO CLOSED_ACCOUNTS VALUES (10);
```

I need to find the PERSON_ID values in CLOSED_ACCOUNTS that have a matching PERSON_ID in either HOUSEHOLD_1, HOUSEHOLD_2, or HOUSEHOLD_3, but do not have a PERSON_ID in HOUSEHOLD_DELETIONS. With the data above, I should only find PERSON_ID values 3 and 6.  I've tried the SQL tricks I know, but I have not been successful, so any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is for Oracle only (as the ddl statements would indicate) you should remove the tag for [tag:sql-server]

Answer (score 0):

SET operations should work to you:

```
SQL> select person_id from CLOSED_ACCOUNTS
  2  intersect (
  3  select person_id from HOUSEHOLD_1
  4  union
  5  select person_id from HOUSEHOLD_2
  6  union
  7  select person_id from HOUSEHOLD_3
  8  )
  9  minus
 10  select person_id from HOUSEHOLD_DELETIONS
 11  /

 PERSON_ID                                                                      
----------                                                                      
         3                                                                      
         6
```